# HiPHP read big file using file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am reading a file of about 250 MB using file_get_contents and getting error

PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 524288) (tried to allocate 231137548 bytes) in /home/

File is saved in same server.

Already added below line in code ini_set('memory_limit', '300M');

Comment: If you're in a shared hosting environment using `ini_set` might return `false` because your hosting provider is not allowing you to override that particular value.

Answer (score 0):

You should increase **memory_limit** php option, for example, to 300mb

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

Comment: Already added below line in code ini_set('memory_limit', '300M');

Comment: does "not want" have a pragmatic justification? If the file was 10 times bigger than your ram would that pragmatic justification still hold?